# How do I convert argv to lpCommandLine parameter of CreateProcess?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, createprocess

Let I want to write an application, that launches another application. Like this:

```
# This will launch another_app.exe
my_app.exe another_app.exe 
# This will launch another_app.exe with arg1, arg and arg3 arguments
my_app.exe another_app.exe arg1 arg2 arg3
```

The problem here is that I'm getting `char* argv[]` in my `main` function, but I need to merge it to `LPTSTR` in order to pass it to `CreateProcess`.

There is a `GetCommandLine` function, but I cannot use it because I'm porting code from Linux and tied to `argc/argv` (otherwise, it's a very ugly hack for me).

I cannot easily merge arguments by hand, because `argv[i]` might contain spaces.

Basically, I want the reverse of `CommandLineToArgvW`. Is there a *standard* way to do this?

Comment: What aspect of this problem are you finding hard?

Comment: I want to be certain my solution is correct and not missing some corner case.  I am hoping in the best case that someone knows of a function in a Windows standard library to do this.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I hope you're joking. Code Review does not tolerate this.

Comment: @Mast Not this question as is. A question with the working code that asker has.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Then first ask the OP to post working code, also to make sure some actually exists.  Don't recommend alternate sites until the question is ready to go.

Comment: @Jamal It would clearly be a different question on a different site. I didn't say, "ask this question there", I said "ask there".

Comment: @Jamal It would be inappropriate to ask the poster to post his working code here, as code review questions are off-topic here. You shouldn't be recommending that people make their posts off-topic.

Comment: @RossRidge Working code with the question "now I need the inverse, what's that?" would most probably be on-topic here and off-topic there (feature requests are off-topic on Code Review). Not all working code on SO is off-topic by default.

Comment: @Mast  He doesn't have any working code that he needs the inverse of. He has a solution to question he asked, but is unsure if it's correct.

Comment: @ivaigult : I don't understand the reluctance to use `GetCommandLine`.  If you are using `CreateProcess`, you are already in non-portable land.  (Or is this about "I have an array of character pointers that my linux-based code is expecting to pass to `exec`, and I want to call `CreateProcess`)

Comment: @MartinBonner I have some code that manipulates with `argv` e.g. adds/removes some arguments depending on some condition. Then, I have a function `void spawn_process(int argc, char** argv)`, which should be cross platform. All the OS aware code works with the function.

Comment: "`argv[i]` might contain spaces" - it can only contain spaces if the argument supplied is quoted: `my_app.exe "another_app.exe arg1 arg2 arg3"`

Comment: People who down-vote this, please, consider adding a comment, what's wrong with this post. As for me, it was useful to know that I should perform quotation on my own and there are pitfalls like @MartinBonner noted.

Comment: @WeatherVane: It is true that to supply an argument that contains spaces you have to quote it, but so what?  The value of `argv[i]` won't contain those quotes - you need to put them back.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The definitive answer on how to quote arguments is on Daniel Colascione's blog:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/twistylittlepassagesallalike/2011/04/23/everyone-quotes-command-line-arguments-the-wrong-way/

I am reluctant to quote the code here because I don't know the license.  The basic idea is:

```
for each single argument:
    if it does not contain  \t\n\v\", 
        just use as is
    else
        output "
        for each character
            backslashes = 0
            if character is backslash
                count how many successive backslashes there are
            fi
            if eow
                output the backslashs doubled
                break
            else if char is "
                output the backslashs doubled
                output \"
            else
                output the backslashes (*not* doubled)
                output character
            fi
        rof
        output "
    fi // needs quoting
rof // each argument
```

If you need to pass the command line to cmd.exe, see the article (it's different).

I think it is crazy that the Microsoft C runtime library doesn't have a function to do this.

Answer (score 5):

There is no Win32 API that does the reverse of `CommandLineToArgvW()`.  You have to format the command line string yourself.  This is nothing more than basic string concatenation.

Microsoft documents the format for command-line arguments (or at least the format expected by VC++-written apps, anyway):

[Parsing C++ Command-Line Arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/17w5ykft.aspx)

> Microsoft C/C++ startup code uses the following rules when
>   interpreting arguments given on the operating system command line:
>
> - Arguments are delimited by white space, which is either a space or a
>     tab.
> - The caret character (^) is not recognized as an escape character or
>     delimiter. The character is handled completely by the command-line
>     parser in the operating system before being passed to the argv array
>     in the program.
> - A string surrounded by double quotation marks ("string") is
>     interpreted as a single argument, regardless of white space contained
>     within. A quoted string can be embedded in an argument.
> - A double quotation mark preceded by a backslash (\") is interpreted
>     as a literal double quotation mark character (").
> - Backslashes are interpreted literally, unless they immediately
>     precede a double quotation mark.
> - If an even number of backslashes is followed by a double quotation
>     mark, one backslash is placed in the argv array for every pair of
>     backslashes, and the double quotation mark is interpreted as a string
>     delimiter.
> - If an odd number of backslashes is followed by a double quotation
>     mark, one backslash is placed in the argv array for every pair of
>     backslashes, and the double quotation mark is "escaped" by the
>     remaining backslash, causing a literal double quotation mark (") to be
>     placed in argv.

It should not be hard for you to write a function that takes an array of strings and concatenates them together, applying the reverse of the above rules to each string in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to recreate the command line, taking care of having all program name and arguments enclosed in `"`. This is done by concatenating a `\"` to these strings, one at the beginning, one at the end.

Assuming the program name to be created is `argv[1]`, the first argument `argv[2]` etc...

```
char command[1024]; // size to be adjusted
int i;
for (*command=0, i=1 ; i<argc ; i++) {
   if (i > 1) strcat(command, " ");
   strcat(command, "\"");
   strcat(command, argv[i]);
   strcat(command, "\"");
}
```

Use the 2<sup>nd</sup> argument of CreateProcess

```
CreateProcess(NULL, command, ...);
```

Comment: Well, you'll also have to escape any `"`,`\ `, and `^` characters present.  Could also make the quoting optional, if `strchr(argv[i], ' ')` or `strchr(argv[i], '\t')`

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b : The question asks about "CreateProcess".  You don't need to quote '^' unless you are going via Cmd.exe.

Comment: You are correct. I figured that out doing my implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the below code if it suits your need, the txt array sz can be used as a string pointer. I have added code support for both Unicode and MBCS,

```
            #include <string>
            #include <vector>

            #ifdef _UNICODE
                #define String std::wstring
            #else
                #define String std::string
            #endif 

            int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
            {
                TCHAR sz[1024] = {0};
                std::vector<String> allArgs(argv, argv + argc);

                for(unsigned i=1; i < allArgs.size(); i++)
                {
                    TCHAR* ptr = (TCHAR*)allArgs[i].c_str();
                    _stprintf_s(sz, sizeof(sz), _T("%s %s"), sz, ptr);
                }

                return 0;
            }
```